# How to determine a bug in a Scrapy item loader implementation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, scrapy, refactoring

I'm attempting a scraping project with the Scrapy framework that requires (I think) that I use item loaders for some of the processing. After getting nowhere I decided to try to refactor the Scrapy [tutorial quotes project](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) to narrow down my issue and I am getting the same errors. I'm fairly certain that I'm making an error with the item loaders on the actual project and here.

items.py:

```
def clean_text(value):
    return value.strip()

class QuoteItem(Item):
    text = scrapy.Field()
    author = scrapy.Field()
    tags = scrapy.Field()


class QuoteLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_input_processor = MapCompose(clean_text)
    default_output_processor = TakeFirst()

    text_in = MapCompose(clean_text)

    author_in = MapCompose(clean_text)

    tags_in = MapCompose(clean_text)
```

quotes_spider(refactored and broken):

```
class QuotesSpider1(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes1"
    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
            load = QuoteLoader(item=QuoteItem(), selector=quote)
            load.add_css('text', 'span.text::text').extract_first()
            load.add_css('author', 'small.author::text').extract_first()
            load.add_css('tags', 'div.tags a.tag::text').extract()
            yield load.load_item()
```

quotes_spider from tutorial(functional):

```
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
            yield {
                'text': quote.css('span.text::text').extract_first(),
                'author': quote.css('small.author::text').extract_first(),
                'tags': quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').extract(),
            }
```

traceback and log:

```
2018-11-04 21:12:24 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.1 started (bot: tutorial)
2018-11-04 21:12:24 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.5.0, libxml2 2.9.8, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 18.9.0, Python 3.6.7 |Anaconda,
 Inc.| (default, Oct 28 2018, 19:44:12) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 18.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018), cryptography 2.3.1, Platform Windows-10-10.0.17134-S
P0
2018-11-04 21:12:24 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'tutorial', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'tutorial.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES
': ['tutorial.spiders']}
2018-11-04 21:12:25 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2018-11-04 21:12:26 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2018-11-04 21:12:26 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2018-11-04 21:12:26 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2018-11-04 21:12:26 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-11-04 21:12:26 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-11-04 21:12:26 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2018-11-04 21:12:27 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.jdpower.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2018-11-04 21:12:28 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.jdpower.com/Cars/2019/Chevrolet> (referer: None)
2018-11-04 21:12:28 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.jdpower.com/Cars/2019/Chevrolet> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ME\Anaconda3\envs\tutorial\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\ME\Anaconda3\envs\tutorial\lib\site-packages\scrapy\commands\parse.py", line 195, in callback
    items, requests = self.run_callback(response, cb)
  File "C:\Users\ME\Anaconda3\envs\tutorial\lib\site-packages\scrapy\commands\parse.py", line 117, in run_callback
    for x in iterate_spider_output(cb(response)):
  File "C:\Users\ME\PycharmProjects\tutorial\tutorial\spiders\msrp_trial_spider.py", line 38, in parse
    load.get_xpath('full_name', '//*[contains(@class,"veh-icons__title")]/text()').extract()
  File "C:\Users\ME\Anaconda3\envs\tutorial\lib\site-packages\scrapy\loader\__init__.py", line 175, in get_xpath
    return self.get_value(values, *processors, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\ME\Anaconda3\envs\tutorial\lib\site-packages\scrapy\loader\__init__.py", line 108, in get_value
    proc = wrap_loader_context(proc, self.context)
  File "C:\Users\ME\Anaconda3\envs\tutorial\lib\site-packages\scrapy\loader\common.py", line 10, in wrap_loader_context
    if 'loader_context' in get_func_args(function):
  File "C:\Users\ME\Anaconda3\envs\tutorial\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 241, in get_func_args
    raise TypeError('%s is not callable' % type(func))
TypeError: <class 'str'> is not callable
2018-11-04 21:12:28 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2018-11-04 21:12:28 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 519,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 22637,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 5, 3, 12, 28, 737277),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'spider_exceptions/TypeError': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 5, 3, 12, 26, 497083)}
2018-11-04 21:12:28 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)

>>> STATUS DEPTH LEVEL 0 <<<
# Scraped Items  ------------------------------------------------------------
[]

# Requests  -----------------------------------------------------------------
[]
```

Comment: It would be much easier to help if your code matched the log.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're calling `.extract_first()` on the result of the `add_css` method, which returns `None`.

Removing such calls should be enough:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
        load = QuoteLoader(item=QuoteItem(), selector=quote)
        load.add_css('text', 'span.text::text')
        load.add_css('author', 'small.author::text')
        load.add_css('tags', 'div.tags a.tag::text')
        yield load.load_item()
```

You'll probably need to customize the [output processor](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#declaring-input-and-output-processors) for the `tags` field, so that you don't use the `TakeFirst()` one, which will result in a single tag per item, which is not true for this website.